# Month start in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to find the starting date of current month in SQL Server 2005 ?

Comment: hey dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one way

```
SELECT DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, getdate()), 0) AS FirstDayOfMonth
```

for last day and other time periods, see here: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/How_to_find_the_first_and_last_days_in_years%2C_months_etc

Comment: +1: Nice method: Get the number of months that have happened, and add them onto the first day.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @mydate DATETIME
SELECT @mydate = GETDATE()
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),DATEADD(dd,-(DAY(@mydate)-1),@mydate),101) AS Date_Value
```

[Get First Day of the Month Function](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/get-first-day-of-month.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There will be loads of ways to do this, and this is one of them:

```
select convert(datetime,convert(varchar(10),getdate() - day(getdate()) + 1,120))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DECLARE @currentmonthstart datetime

 SET @currentmonthstart = DATEADD(DD, -DATEPART(DD, GETDATE())+1, getdate())

 PRINT @currentmonthstart
```